# Ao clicar no menu do site, mover a barra de rolagem para um ponto específico lentamente

Tags: jquery, html

Gostaria de mover a barra de rolagem para um ponto específico da pagina ao clicar no menu do site.

Eu consegui fazer com âncoras.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
     $(".scroll").click(function(event){        
         event.preventDefault();
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 600);
  });
}); 

 <a href="#footer" class="scroll">Descer</a>
```

Estou tentando fazer clicando no menu, mas não consegui até o momento.

Comment: Não vejo essa pergunta como duplicata identificada, uma vez que se refere a clicar no menu do site, e não a um link fora do menu.

Comment: Não vejo como o lugar do link faria diferença. Se você quer perguntar "como faço para ir automaticamente pra uma ancora ao carregar a pagina", é outro problema (mas ai é completamente diferente da sua pergunta atual).

Comment: tranquilo, desculpe então por perguntar errado. Da próxima vez irei prestar mais atenção em como perguntar corretamente para que não haja problema.

Comment: Não estou me queixando, nao precisa pedir desculpas. Só estou apontando coisas que vc pode melhorar pra obter respostas que sejam relevantes pro seu problema. Lembrando que se é esse o caso, você pode [edit] sua postagem pra acrescentar todas as informações que forem relevantes para o problema. A idéia é que quanto mais fácil ficar da comunidade entender o problema exato, maior a chance de você conseguir o que quer, e ao mesmo tempo do pessoal não perder tempo respondendo algo que não é o que você espera.

Comment: PS: da forma que vc [refez a pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141804/70), ficou melhor e já veio resposta mais adequada, creio eu. A idéia é essa, vc aproveitar melhor o site, e a comunidade poder gastar melhor o tempo te ajudando objetivamente. Inclusive quando fiz o 1o comentário, nem tinha visto aquela ainda.

Comment: sim, é que estou aprendendo programação e gosto muito desse site pois tem resposta para quase tudo. Vou aprender perguntar também corretamente com o tempo.

Answer (score 3):

Olá, companheiro.

O plugin sugerido pelo nosso companheiro Naldson deve funcionar perfeitamente, porém, também é possível fazer sem a instalação desse plugin, somente com JS e jQuery. Confira:

```
$("html, body").animate({
                   scrollTop: /*Distância em relação ao topo (int, em pixels)*/
              }, /*Duração da animação (int, em milisegundos)*/);
```

Então, ficaria por exemplo:

```
$("html, body").animate({
                   scrollTop: 1300
              }, 200);
```

Se você quiser rolar, por exemplo, até um elemento em específico, você pode usar o método .offset().top desse elemento para pegar a distância dele em relação ao topo (não esqueça de subtrair a altura do seu topo caso ele seja position:fixed). Exemplo:

```
$("html, body").animate({
                   scrollTop: $("#id_do_bendito").offset().top
              }, 200);


//Com topo position:fixed, considerando que o topo é #topo

topoHt = $("#topo").height();

$("html, body").animate({
                   scrollTop: $("#id_do_bendito").offset().top-topoHt 
              }, 200);
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, mas na mesma página. O meu caso específico é que venho de outra página após clicar no menu da pagina anterior.

Comment: Se eu entendi direito.... é bem tranquilo de fazer, coloque a função de rolagem dentro de: $(window).load(function(){/*aqui*/}); que ela vai rolar na hora que carregar essa nova página.

Comment: Melhor resposta!

Answer (score 2):

Conhece o [Animate Scroll](http://plugins.compzets.com/animatescroll/)? Ele faz exatamente o que você quer.

Com ele você poderia fazer assim:

Index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="animatescroll.js">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav id="menu">
           <ul>
              <button onclick='$('.elemento').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:2000,easing:'easeInOutBack'});'>Ir até o elemento</li>
           </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="elemento">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: vou ver. obrigado.